# "failed to fetch" error while installing Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, apache2

I am trying to install Apache2 on the Ubuntu Container(based on [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) official Docker Image). The container runs on Ubuntu 18.04. On running `apt install apache2`, I get the following error.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.173 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I did use `apt update && upgrade` before running the install command.

The error may seem to imply that the link `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb` might not be available currently, but that is not the case. I manually opened the above link and could download the .deb file myself, but for some reason, it cannot be fetched by the installer.